# JavaScript - Image style changes not functioning properly

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

So this is what's up:

```
onmouseover="imageOn(bg-index);" onmouseout="imageOff(bg-index);"
```

Those are two attributes I have on a `table` with ID `table-title`. The functions are a part of a remote JS file:

```
if (name == 'bg-index') { document.getElementById("table-title").style.backgroundImage = "url('images/bg-index.png')"; }
```

...with `imageOff` being the same thing but with a different image. This doesn't work; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: missing quotes around strings: onmouseover="imageOn('bg-index');" onmouseout="imageOff('bg-index');"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onmouseover="imageOn('bg-index');" onmouseout="imageOff('bg-index');"
```

Try it with the function variables as strings.

Answer (score 0):

CSS has a specific hierarchy. Did you check if there are any other CSS entries that overwrite what you are trying to change? Perhaps there is some selector that is forcing that image as "always on".

There are four distinct categories which define the specificity level of a given selector:

1. Inline styles (Presence of style in document).
   An inline style lives within your XHTML document. It is attached directly to the element to be styled.
   E.g. `<h1 style="color: #fff;">`
2. IDs (# of ID selectors)
   ID is an identifier for your page elements, such as `#div`.
3. Classes, attributes and pseudo-classes (# of class selectors).
   This group includes `.classes`, `[attributes]` and pseudo-classes such as `:hover`, `:focus` etc.
4. Elements and pseudo-elements (# of Element (type) selectors).
   Including for instance `:before` and `:after`.